# SQL - How to get first and last record from union table?

Tags: php, sql

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT id_product, picture_url, product_name, product_price, tracking_link, '$ecommerce2->nama_ecommerce' AS table_identity FROM table1 WHERE product_name LIKE '%$search%'
                    UNION
SELECT id_product, picture_url, product_name, product_price, tracking_link, '$ecommerce2->nama_ecommerce' AS table_identity FROM table2 WHERE product_name LIKE '%$search%'
            ) AS big_table ORDER BY big_table.product_price DESC
            LIMIT 1
```

How to get first and the last record from sql above?

Comment: Do you mean without a `Limit` on it? You'll only get 1 record at most with this query so that result is your first and last record.

Comment: yeah without limit or any else

Comment: yeah without limit or any else, that's my old query
so need a query that can get first and last record
thanks @TahTatsumoto

Comment: What kind of SQL database are you using? Are you looking to have a query that solves this problem or do you want to do it programmatically in PHP? In PHP you can retrieve the array and just do `index = 0` and `index = length - 1`

Comment: i'm lookng to have a query that solve my problem.
i'm programming at php

Comment: What is this union? Do you have two tables storing identical data? You should merge them.

Comment: Make sure to use prepared statements with SQL parameters, instead of interpolating string values into your query string. This is a security risk.

Answer (score 0):

just toggle between `desc` (for last record) and `asc` (for first record)
and `limit 1` for only one record.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your Union is duplicated for a reason:

```
SELECT * FROM (
   SELECT id_product, picture_url, product_name, product_price, tracking_link, '$ecommerce2->nama_ecommerce' AS table_identity FROM table1 WHERE product_name LIKE '%$search%'
                    UNION ALL
   SELECT id_product, picture_url, product_name, product_price, tracking_link, '$ecommerce2->nama_ecommerce' AS table_identity FROM table2 WHERE product_name LIKE '%$search%'
 ) AS big_table1 ORDER BY product_price LIMIT 1

UNION

SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT id_product, picture_url, product_name, product_price, tracking_link, '$ecommerce2->nama_ecommerce' AS table_identity FROM table1 WHERE product_name LIKE '%$search%'
                        UNION ALL
    SELECT id_product, picture_url, product_name, product_price, tracking_link, '$ecommerce2->nama_ecommerce' AS table_identity FROM table2 WHERE product_name LIKE '%$search%'
 ) AS big_table2 ORDER BY product_price DESC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: sorry, that UNION is from diferent table. I had change my post. Thanks

Comment: I've updated my answer. Basics are the same. You need to query the data twice, get the first record Ascending. Then order the records Descending and get the first record.

Comment: i had try that query. it show "Incorrect usage of UNION and ORDER BY"

Answer (score 0):

```
(SELECT * FROM (
   SELECT id_product, picture_url, product_name, product_price, tracking_link, '$ecommerce2->nama_ecommerce' AS table_identity FROM table1 WHERE product_name LIKE '%$search%'
                    UNION ALL
   SELECT id_product, picture_url, product_name, product_price, tracking_link, '$ecommerce2->nama_ecommerce' AS table_identity FROM table2 WHERE product_name LIKE '%$search%'
 ) AS big_table1 ORDER BY product_price LIMIT 1)

UNION

(SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT id_product, picture_url, product_name, product_price, tracking_link, '$ecommerce2->nama_ecommerce' AS table_identity FROM table1 WHERE product_name LIKE '%$search%'
                        UNION ALL
    SELECT id_product, picture_url, product_name, product_price, tracking_link, '$ecommerce2->nama_ecommerce' AS table_identity FROM table2 WHERE product_name LIKE '%$search%'
 ) AS big_table2 ORDER BY product_price DESC LIMIT 1)
```